# Update cookies on watch Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently implementing the cookies.
I have the cookies to be set on mounted, and this cookie has an empty object initially.
As soon as the object gets filled, I am watching the object getting updated, and here is where I want to update my cookie, however, it does not get updated on watch.
I will put a draft just below.

```
   <template>
         <details @detailsCompleted="savedDetails"></details>
    </template>


      data() {
         return {
               obj:{}
         }
            },

    methods: {
    savedDetails: function(objectPassed) {
    this.obj = objectPassed;
    }
    }
     mounted: function() {
           this.obj = {};
            Cookies.set("name", JSON.stringify(this.obj), {expires: '1m'});
            Cookies.get("name");

        }

        watch: {
        obj: {
        handler: function(val){
        Cookies.set("name", JSON.stringify(val), {expires: '1m'});
         Cookies.get("name");

        }
    }
```

I can see that the cookies get initialised, and has empty obj, however, does not get updated on watch, how can I achieve this?? Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, you could use [vue-reactive-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-reactive-cookie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply update the cookie along with the saveDetails method like this

```
<template>
   <details @detailsCompleted="savedDetails"></details>
 </template>

 data() {
   return {
     obj:{}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    savedDetails: function(objectPassed) {
      this.obj = objectPassed;
      Cookies.set("name", JSON.stringify(objectPassed), {expires: '1m'});
      Cookies.get("name");
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.obj = {};
    Cookies.set("name", JSON.stringify(this.obj), {expires: '1m'});
    Cookies.get("name");
  }
```

EDIT:

https://jsfiddle.net/k85o7bdq/

Here's a working fiddle.

Perhaps You're trying to determine if cookie was updated by looking at the Application tab in dev tools? There's a little refresh button there, try clicking it after updating the cookies.

Comment: I have tried this before I posted the issue, and it did not help

Comment: You sure the cookie is setting in the first place? It seems that js-cookie library doesnt support string expires format, only a Number or a Date object. This might be giving an error and stopping the cookie from being set.

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure it does get set in the first place as I can see "name" ... ,  and clears off after 1m.

Comment: Well, check the fiddle, its working perfectly there.

Comment: I have done the same thing and it does not work in my case with an object. I have tried with a string instead, and it works just fine, without having to hit any refresh button in the tool. Also on mounted, I have noticed that under the field "value" my object has "%7B%7D", rather than be just an empty object {}, as displayed when I check the tool on your fiddle.

Comment: Well, I have tried this in a brand new page, and it worked, now I gotta figure out what is happening on the page where I was initially trying to do so, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `obj` inside the `mounted` hook is locally scoped. If you don't declare it inside your component's `data` function or as a computed property, the watcher doesn't see it because it is not reactive.

Try:

```
data () {
    return {
      obj: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$set(this, 'obj', {name: 'hello', age:'10', gender: 'not to say'});
    Cookies.set("name", JSON.stringify(this.obj), {expires: '1m'});
    Cookies.get("name");
  }
```

**Later edit:** Based on your comment bellow, and the updated code snippet, I still suspect your problem is caused by incorrectly updating your local state.

Since your object is initialized as an empty literal, when you update it with    `this.obj = objectPassed;` in `savedDetails` you are essentially creating new properties on the object. This type of update will not be reactive, and therefore, your watcher will not do anything. The correct way to ensure reactivity is:

`this.$set(this, 'obj', objectPassed);`

Read more about reactivity caveats in the official documentation on the topic "[Reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)"

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have just updated the post, on mounted the object in empty, gets emitted filled in from the child, to parent component (which is where I am setting the cookie), and then I am watching into obj as the value might change, and with the updated obj I want to set/update the cookie.
So on mounted my obj won't have the attributes set.

Comment: Could you please edit your snipped code, as I have tried to figure out what you meant by reading your comment and implement it but it did not seem to be solving the issue, thanks.